# Is there a keyboard shortcut to quickly find and open a file in Visual Studio 2005/2008 like how they do it in TextMate?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to quickly find and open a file in Visual Studio 2005/2008 like how they do it in TextMate?

In textmate <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in Textmate brings up something that you can type a few key which would display all relevant files and allow you to quickly select one, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> back and forth also allows you to quickly alternate between 2 files most recently used. This is extremely helpful.

I am aware that there is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> which shows a list of all open documents which is almost there but not quite.

Answer (score 4):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go to the search box, then type **>of filename** (with autocomplete).

You can also do this and other commands in the [command window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) or the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Or, if you don't mind buying, ReSharper has [Go to File](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_File) which I highly recommend. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and it brings up a nice search dialog that supports wildcards and other shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Sonic File Finder is a free VS plugin which is basically the same thing, and quite well-loved by most people who install it.

http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is the following

> CTRL + , (comma) then type your file/class/method name

Answer (score 2):

I've made an extension that works exactly like Textmate's "go to file" feature: https://github.com/maxt3r/VS-CmdT

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the search box in visual studio and type ">open " and then start typing, autocomplete will come up for all the files in your solution. This is in 2008, not so sure about 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box in Visual Studio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will toggle between the two most recent files.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Resharper works just like you describe. It provides a text box in which you type the filename and it generates a live list from which you can pick from. Nice features include wildcarding (e.g. Customer*xaml) and matching on camel case filenames (e.g. SVD will match SingleValueDecomposition.cs). At my work, if people use one feature of Resharper, it will be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

If you code in C++ rather than C#, then Visual Assist provides some functionality. And in my opinion, works better than Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

Sara Ford has a blog post about this: [Did you know... How to open a file in the solution without using either a tool window or a dialog?](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/03/04/did-you-know-how-to-open-a-file-in-the-solution-without-using-either-a-tool-window-or-a-dialog.aspx)

All the previous responses are accurate and are mentioned in her post and the comments. In addition, another approach is to launch the command window using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then typing in "of filename" or "open filename" in the same way mentioned for the search field.

@Adam Neal mentioned ReSharper. Another popular tool is [CodeRush/Refactor! Pro](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/) and it also has a file navigation window that can be launched (and searched) via the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut.