# Visual Studio 2010 - Anything like textmate's cmd+t function?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there anything like Textmate's Command+T functionality available in Visual Studio 2010? Third party plugin suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

> CTRL + , (comma) then type your file/class/method name

**hope this helps**

Comment: Perfect! And even better that it searches for classes as well as methods.

Comment: Yes! CTRL + , is really powerful. Every user of Visual Studio should know about that. Have a good time. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I've just scratched my own itch and made an extension that replicates TextMate's "go to file" feature entirely, along with fuzzy search: https://github.com/maxt3r/VS-CmdT

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474941/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-quickly-find-and-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-20) seems to be asking the same thing. Maybe you can find some suggestions there.

Comment: toally missed that one in my search, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

For those using earlier versions of Visual Studio, the [Sonic File Finder plugin](http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm) accomplishes the same functionality.